# Is it possible to have a Web App with Local Notifications in the following scenario?

Tags: javascript, push-notification, notifications, single-page-application, service-worker

I would like to know if the following scenario is possible:

- I have a SPA made with VUE 3
- I have a calendar that is synchronized with indexedDB each time I access it.
- It has to work in most browsers on the market

Can I put a service worker that reads indexedDB and show notifications to the users?
Can this service worker-run iteratively from time to time to read data?
Can this service worker run to read previous data if the web app is not loaded in any tab of the browser?

If one of any questions is "NO", the only alternative is to push notifications?

Thanks